# Faster R-CNN - why do we need a classifier after the region proposal network?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

It is my understanding that the region proposal network performs both classification, to find out if a certain box contains foreground or background, and regression, to fine tune the locations of the boxes.
In that case,why do we need an additional classifier after the RPN? The classification has already been performed.

Answer (score 0):

To classify each ROI into one of the $K$ categories (such as cat, dog, car, truck, etc).

Comment: Thanks! So if I only need to detect 1 class(for example face detection), The output from the RPN is enough?

Comment: @Tsahi sure, yes

Comment: Another question: Why does the second classifier also performs a regression in order to refine the box? the boxes have already been refined by the RPN's regression.

Comment: Here is an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976254/faster-rcnn-why-dont-we-just-use-only-rpn-for-detection